# Temporary folder for uploads

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, microsoft-web-deploy

I want to create a temporary folder to store uploads in my application. I've added the folder to my application and it works fine during development.

However when I publish to my test server, the folder doesn't get published unless it has a file in it.  On top of that, the permissions are wrong on the folder and I need to manually change them by logging onto the test server and doing it through explorer.  I am using ClickOnce WebDeploy to publish to the test server.

Is there a better option than the way I'm doing it?  Or some way to set the permissions on the folder at publish time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To automate the setting of folder permissions, see
http://sedodream.com/2011/11/08/SettingFolderPermissionsOnWebPublish.aspx

To get the folder to be deployed, the easiest way is to just put a dummy file, like a .txt file with nothing in it, in the folder in your project.  Web Deploy won't copy a folder that is empty.

Answer (score 0):

The "official" way to do this is to use [WebDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy), however this is not a simple undertaking and requires a lot of work to setup, configure, then create deploy scripts for your site.

You don't mention what method you're using to publish.  FTP?  File System?

Comment: I'm just using the inbuilt publish in VS, i think its called ClickOnce?

Comment: @link664 - yes, but there are several methods of using that.  FTP, FileSystem, Webdeploy, etc..

Comment: And is there a better way to do this than creating my own folder? Such as using the system temp folder or something?